# date (time) conversion in a long shape dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

This is a screenshot of my data frame. The data frame is long (each row included multiple measurements for each patient_id). The number of repeated measurement (rows) is different for each patient_id. In R software,  I want to generate a new date variable as each date (in order) minus the first date and save it as days.

[image]

Comment: can you dput your data ?

Comment: Edit your question to add the output of `dput(head(df,10))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dplyr you should group by id and then mutate to add a the new column as follow.

```
library(tidyverse)

# example data frame (always dput a simple piece of your data)
df <- structure(list(patient_id = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
  2L, 2L), date = structure(c(17600, 17601, 17602, 17603, 17604, 
  17605, 17606, 17607, 17608, 17609), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

The key is to store your date variable as a date object in your data frame, this way you can do arithmetic with it. To convert your date variable you can use `as_date` function from the `lubridate` package.

```
df %>%
  group_by(patient_id) %>% # group by patient
  mutate(days_since_first_time = date - min(date)) %>% 
  arrange(patient_id, date)

# this is the output
patient_id  date        days_since_first_time
1           2018-03-10  0
1           2018-03-14  4
1           2018-03-18  8
2           2018-03-11  0
2           2018-03-12  1
2           2018-03-13  2
2           2018-03-15  4
2           2018-03-16  5
2           2018-03-17  6
2           2018-03-19  8
```

Comment: How can I select only the first measurement which located in an interval of 2 ±1 day?

Comment: add another pipe filtering the result like `%>% filter(days_since_first_time %in% 1:3)`

Comment: Thanks Johan. Your filter pipe gives multiple measurements for each patient_id. So far so good. How can I select only one unique measurement which is closer to a value (for example 1 in your example).

Comment: adding another filter where `%>% filter(days _since_first_time  == min(days_since_first_time)`

Comment: You should consider reading about `dplyr` package. It is usefull in this kind of data manipulations.